# How do I include an svg image in exported html file using emacs org-mode?

Tags: html, org-mode

I've tried the following syntax:

```
[[folder/figure.svg]]
```

along with `org-export-as-html`.

This apparently does not work - just adds a reference ... in the html file.

Comment: What version of Org are you running?  I just tested with 7.8.03 and it properly displayed the image.

Comment: Thanks - I was using 7.0.1. I just switched to 7.8.03, but get same thing, except that now the footer does indicate that the document was exported as XHTML.

Comment: And now the html document shows an `img src` line instead of `a href` reference for the figure. But does not show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to test this a couple times to clarify exactly what the issue appeared to be.  The image exports successfully when I use the following link:

```lisp
Current folder is ~/test/
[[./img/Bitmap.svg]]
[[./Bitmap.svg]]
[[~/test/Bitmap.svg]]
```

However it fails with:

```lisp
Current folder is ~/test/
[[img/Bitmap.svg]]
[[Bitmap.svg]]
```

I suspect it is that Org has to find where on the path the image is, the `./` tells it to look from current location, while `~/` can be properly expanded by the shell to give the current directory.

If you prefix `./` to your images they should export correctly.

Comment: Thanks - I was also using a `file:` prefix in which case you don't need the `./`... but I think one of the reasons why it wasn't showing up is because I was viewing it in Firefox. In Chrome or Opera, it loads okay now (once I upgraded the org version)...

Answer (score 1):

In Org mode, the `org-export-html-inline-image-extensions` variable determines which image files get inlined and not linked in the html output.  You should also check the settings of the `org-export-html-inline-images` variable, in case also other types of images do not get inlined.

To customize these options, you can

```
M-x customize-option org-export-html-inline-image-extensions
```

or use the menu 'Options > Customize Emacs > Specific Option' in case you have a GUI available.

Comment: Thanks - I did edit that variable, but seems to not require it?